# Storing dynamic feild data to database in jquery mobile and php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am creating an order page in Jquery Mobile where user fill data and quantity .

**Creating Dynamic Fields**

Whenever user fills the data in quantity, say use entered 1, then only one dynamic field will generate. code below

HTML

```
<label for="textarea2b">Quantity</label>
<input type="number" name="name2" id="quantitypickup" onkeyup="showdimension()" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="">
  <div id="dimshow" class="row">
```

JS to show dynamic field

```
function showdimension() {
    var q = $("#quantitypickup").val();
    var r = $("#dimshow");
    if (q == "0" || q == "" || q == null) {
        r.hide();
        r.html('');
    } else {
        r.show();
        r.html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            r.append('  <div class="col-xs-6"><label>Item Name ' + (i + 1) + '</label><input type="text" name="name2" id="itemname" onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-xs-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Length</label><input type="number" id="length" name="name2"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Width</label><input type="number" name="name2" id="width"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Height</label><input type="number" id="height" name="name2" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div></div> </div></div>');

        }

    }
}
```

I want to insert this into database using mysql and php how can I do so.
Below is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ankit10594/5suemmyk/
Please help

Comment: As per my understanding you want to store the value of 'Item Name 1','width','Height' fields value...right?

Comment: Yes, i want to store the item name [] , width height length

Answer (score 0):

In js: update id & name field

```
for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            r.append('  <div class="col-xs-6"><label>Item Name ' + (i + 1) + '</label><input type="text" name="itemname_'+(i+1)+'" id="itemname_'+(i+1)+'" onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-xs-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Length</label><input type="number" id="length_'+(i+1)+'" name="length_'+(i+1)+'"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Width</label><input type="number" name="width_'+(i+1)+'" id="width_'+(i+1)+'"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Height</label><input type="number" id="height_'+(i+1)+'" name="height_'+(i+1)+'" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div></div> </div></div>');

        }
```

Now put all this div & Html inside a `<form method='POST' action='<your_page name.php'>` tag. & create a submit button. Inside your .php page you can get the value of Quantity from $_POST["name2"].Now useing `for()` insert the data into database.